# When using soft asserts in SpecFlow the test case in the extent report shows test as passed but should be failed

Tags: c#, reporting, bdd, specflow, extentreports

I am working with a testing framework that uses BDD approach (SpecFlow), C# and ExtentReports for reporting.

I'm using soft asserts for my steps to be able to continue executing. The issue is that the test case that is FAILING locally is marked as PASSED in extent reports. How can i set status for the step definition FAILED in order to see the test case is marked as FAILED in extent reports as well? Here is my SofAssert class:

```
public static class SoftAssert    {

private static readonly ThreadLocal<List<string>> _assertionsMessages = new ThreadLocal<List<string>>();
        
public static void Add(Action action)         {
      _assertionsMessages.Value ? ?=new List < string > ();
      try {
        action.Invoke();
      }
      catch(Exception exception) {
        _assertionsMessages.Value.Add(exception.Message);
        LogError(exception.Message);
      }
    }
    public static void AssertAll() {
  
      Logger.Info("-----------Test Finished-----------");
      if (_assertionsMessages.Value == null || _assertionsMessages.Value.Count == 0) return;
      var messages = new List < string > (_assertionsMessages.Value);
      _assertionsMessages.Value.Clear();
      throw new AssertionException(messages);
    }

private static void LogError(string message)
        {
            Logger.Fatal("ERROR => !!!!!!");
            Logger.Fatal($"         {message}");
            Logger.Fatal("         !!!!!!");
        }
    }
```

here is AssertionException :

```
public class AssertionException : NUnit.Framework.AssertionException
    {
        public AssertionException(List<string> assertsMessages) : base($"\nAsserts fails:\n{GetFormattedLog(assertsMessages)}")
        {

        }

    private static string GetFormattedLog(List<string> assertsMessages)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        assertsMessages.ForEach(message => stringBuilder.AppendLine(message));
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

And here is my hooks from BaseTest class:

```
[BeforeFeature]
        public static void BeforeFeature(FeatureContext featureContext)
        {
            _featureName = _extentReporter.CreateTest<Feature>(featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title);
        }

    [BeforeScenario]
public void BeforeScenario()
{
  _scenarioName = _featureName.CreateNode < Scenario > (_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
}


    [AfterStep]
        public void InsertReportingSteps()
        {
            var stepType = _scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.StepDefinitionType.ToString();

            if (_scenarioContext.TestError == null)
            {
                switch (stepType)
                {
                    case "Given":
                        _scenarioName.CreateNode<Given>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text);
                        break;
                    case "When":
                        _scenarioName.CreateNode<When>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text);
                        break;
                    case "Then":
                        _scenarioName.CreateNode<Then>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text);
                        break;
                    case "And":
                        _scenarioName.CreateNode<And>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if (_scenarioContext.TestError != null)
            {                
                switch (stepType)
                {
                    case "Given":
                        _scenarioName.CreateNode<Given>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Fail(_scenarioContext.TestError.Message);
  
                        break;
                    case "When":
                        _scenarioName.CreateNode<When>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Fail(_scenarioContext.TestError.Message);

                        break;
                    case "Then":
                        _scenarioName.CreateNode<Then>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Fail(_scenarioContext.TestError.Message);
                        break;
                    case "And":
                        _scenarioName.CreateNode<And>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Fail(_scenarioContext.TestError.Message);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if (_scenarioContext.ScenarioExecutionStatus.ToString().Equals("StepDefinitionPending"))
            {
                switch (stepType)
                {
                    case "Given":
                        _scenarioName.CreateNode<Given>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
                        break;
                    case "When":
                        _scenarioName.CreateNode<When>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
                        break;
                    case "Then":
                        _scenarioName.CreateNode<Then>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
                        break;
                    case "And":
                        _scenarioName.CreateNode<And>(_scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text).Skip("Step Definition Pending");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }


[AfterScenario]
        public static void TearDownReport()
        {
            try
            {
                SoftAssert.AssertAll();
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    _extentReporter.Flush();
                    
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException e)
                {
                    //ignored
                }
            }  
        }
```

the test is :

```
[When(@"Get Alert")]
    public void WhenTheFirstNumberIsAdded()
    {
        var alert = _Client.GetAlert();
// Making the test to FAIL. Checking status code equal to 400 
            SoftAssert.Add(() => alert.SuccessModel.StatusCode.Should().Be(400));  
        }
```

Comment: Where is the method : LogError()?

Comment: just added LogError method

Comment: I do not see anything obviously wrong.  Maybe it is a flush error and the message isn't getting saved to the file.  See : https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1111?force_isolation=true

Comment: The problem is that Add() method marks test case as PASSED in order to go to the next step via try{} catch{} block, and once extent report is generated it doesn't see any failures. Locally i do get AssertionException.  My assumption is: i need to add the possibility to set status of running step definition and append that AssertionException but i stuck to achieve that

Comment: Then in the exception your need to throw another exception so the error is caught at parent code.

Comment: Alright, I guess i need to set step definition status as FAILED in that exception  but how can i achieve that?

Comment: I see few issues with the code. First you are getting a response from a server in your controller.  So your code is deserializing the <Scenario> object.  If you are not getting a 200 OK (a 400/500 error) they will not be a Scenario.  The Scenario is the body of the response and an Empty Senario is not being handled in the code.  The second issue is you should be validating the Scenario response instead of the Entity database (_scenarioContext),The third issue is the context of the Entiry database _scenarioContext.  Was a query every performed when you code started to fill the _scenarioContext?

Comment: Are you sure the failures are not `InvalidOperationException`s? You are ignoring those in the AfterScenario.